# How do you merge two dataframes and conditionally merge one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes that are identical except for one column. I am hoping to merge the two together and conditionally accept the value of the column. In this case I am look for the max of the two, but in general any conditional would be ideal.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Tom', 30], ['Jane', 40], ['Barry', 22], ['Kelly', 15]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['Tom', 10], ['Jane', 50], ['Barry', 22]])
```

df1:

```
       0   1
0    Tom  30
1   Jane  40
2  Barry  22
3  Kelly  15
```

df2

```
       0   1
0    Tom  10
1   Jane  50
2  Barry  22
```

I am looking to end up with a data frame that merges the two and takes the max of column 1.

Example:

```
       0   1
0    Tom  30
1   Jane  50
2  Barry  22
3  Kelly  15
```

Comment: Try ``df1.merge(df2, how='outer').groupby(0, as_index = False, sort=False).max()``

Comment: Perfect, thanks! This gets me to where I can generalize it myself.

Comment: @sammywemmy You should write that as an answer so OP can check it off as correct. This way, people filtering for unanswered questions won't come here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge the data, setting `how` as `outer`, before grouping to get the `max`:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer').groupby(0, as_index = False, sort=False).max()

       0   1
0    Tom  30
1   Jane  50
2  Barry  22
3  Kelly  15
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way; append, sort_values and drop_duplicates. Code below

```
df2.append(df1).sort_values(by=['0',"1"],ascending = (False, True)).drop_duplicates(subset=['0'],keep='last')

      0   1
0    Tom  30
3  Kelly  15
1   Jane  50
2  Barry  22
```